# CUDA device seems to be blocked

Tags: linux, cuda, nvidia, hpc

I'm running a small CUDA application: the QuickSort benchmark algorithm (see [here](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/research/group/dcs/gpuqsortdcs.html)). I have a dual system with a NVIDIA 660GTX (device 0) and 8600GTS (device 1).

Under Windows 8 and Visual Studio, the application compiles and runs flawlessly on device 0. Under Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS), the app compiles with nvcc and gcc but suddenly stops in its tracks, returning a `(unspecified launch failure)`.

I have two issues:

1. After this error, my GPU cannot perform some other operations, e.g., running the SDK example `bandwidhtTest` blocks when it performs the first data transfer, but running `deviceQuery` continues to perform well. **How can I reset my GPU?** I've already tried the `cudaDeviceReset()` method but it doesn't help
2. **How can I find what is going wrong under linux?** Has someone a clue or seen this before?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Grepping in `dmesg` for NVRM messages can usually give more insight into what is going on. Can you attach log from `sudo nvidia-bug-report.sh`?

Comment: 'dmesg' gives 'NVRM: Xid (0000:01:00): 31, Ch 00000005, engmask 00000101, intr 10000000'. How/where can I attach the bug report? (sorry quite new to Stackoverflow)

Comment: Thanks! Stack overflow doesn't allow attachments. You need to use one of the external file/text hosting services. Output of `nvidia-bug-report.sh` is just a gzipped text so you can e.g. post it on http://pastebin.com/

Answer (score 1):

1. Using the nvidia-smi utility you can reset the GPU if it is compatible
2. To my knowledge and experience, `(unspecified launch failure)` usually referees to segmentation fault. Have you specified the right GPU to use? Try to use cuda-memcheck to see if there is any memory out of bound scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but nvidia-smi cannot reset GeForce devices (it correctly reports memory usage of both devices though). Any other idea how I could achieve such a reset (without having to power off/on the whole desktop)? Also tried cuda-memcheck, but as the app is blocking, I don't get any useful information.

Comment: Have you checked if the process is still running? And thus blocking the card!?

Comment: Checked - the process is not running (it exits with an error code of 1).

Comment: Hm, have no more clue about how to unblock the GPU. Regarding the application, my guess is that it is compiled differently under windows and linux, if you can, see what parameters is passed to nvcc under windows, or just try to add -arch=compute_xx -code=sm_xx to the Makefile where nvcc is present. Where xx represent your compute capability

Comment: Thanks anyway, maybe someone else will come with the 'reset' answer. For the app, I'll continue to dive into it to understand where it is going wrong. One thing: my Linux is x64, while my Win 8 is x86 - that might be the source of the problem (possibly a wrong memory alignment).

Comment: @ZeJibe It should not really matter, but you can try specify everything as int32_t if it is integers you use.

Comment: Made some progress: I got the application to run under Linux by compiling it in debug mode ('nvcc -G -g ...'). If I recompile it without these options, it hangs. See also my reply above on the error message returned in 'dmesg'.

Comment: The specific reset command is `sudo nvidia-smi --gpu-reset -i [gpu_id]`. See [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/11-gb-of-gpu-ram-used-and-no-process-listed-by-nvidia-smi/44459) Nvidia forum thread for more discussion

Answer (score 0):

From my experience XID 31 was always caused by accessing bad pointer (aka Memory access violation).

I'd first pursue this trail. Run your application with [cuda memcheck](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-memcheck). Like that `cuda-memcheck you_app args to your app` and see if it finds any wrong memory accesses.
Also try stepping though the code with `cuda-gdb` or [Nsight Eclipse Edition](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nsight.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using

> cuda-memcheck -b ...

prevents the device from locking up.